# description of message that triggered a method invocation

Tags: objective-c-runtime

Does the objective-c runtime allow getting a description of the message that triggered a method invocation - from within that method itself?

For example, if I have a method called: -(Foobar)doMyStuff; . . is it possible from within that method to get something like:

```
//This would return @"doMyStuff"
NSString* selectorName = [foobar nameOfMessageThatTriggeredMyInvocation];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Every method has its selector passed in as a hidden argument. It's the second argument, after `self`, and it is named `_cmd`:

```
NSString * selectorName = NSStringFromSelector(_cmd);
```

That's why `objc_msgSend(id self, SEL _cmd, ...)` looks the way it does, and why, if you construct an `NSInvocation`, you start at index 2 when setting your arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Josh's answer is totally correct, I might also add that this is useful for logging.

```
Class myClass = object_getClass(self);
NSLog(@"I am in %c[%@ %s]", class_isMetaClass(myClass) ? '+' : '-', myClass, sel_getName(_cmd));
```

"I am in -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]"

Although it's probably easier to use -

```
NSLog(@"So pretty %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

"So pretty -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]"

Which gets inserted at compile time, and is certainly faster. If you do any dynamic method resolution though using _cmd is extremely helpful.