# hidden arguments in objc_msgSend function

Tags: objective-c, runtime

As we know, a message [receiver message] will be converted into a function objc_msgSend(receiver, selector), and finally the objc_msgSend function may finds the procedure that implements the method and calls it. After located the procedure, the function will passes the procedure two hidden arguments: The receiving object & The selector for the method.

My question is: is that ‘receiving object’ means the parameter ‘receiver’ in objc_msgSend(receiver, selector), and is that ‘selector’ means the parameter ‘selector’ in  objc_msgSend(receiver, selector)?

Comment: The answer is simply "yes", although the arguments are called `self` and `_cmd`; this is pretty clear from documentation. Not really sure what you're looking for, but bbum goes into some good detail at the linked question. See also: [Description of message that triggered a method invocation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14421494)

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: Sure, hope you got what you needed!